# VARIANT cloning in ActiveX

Tags: javascript, c++, variant, activexobject, cloning

I'm programming an application in javascript which uses activeX object.
The ActiveX function gets a *VARIANT* parameter from javascript call.

If I define a global variable named **V1* and compare it to the get variable, like this:

```
V1 = &variant;
```

It doesn't work because the data lost after function ends.

How can I clone the *variant* safely and easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `VariantCopy` function ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221697%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

```
VARIANT v1;
VariantCopy(&v1, &variant);
```